# Looping Survdiff

Tags: r

Fairly simple question, but my R knowledge is not great.

**Introduction**

I'm using the package Survdiff. Using it once is fine, but I want to loop it through many variables.

For example: I have a data.frame of 43000 variables with 177 observations. The data.frame also has 3 initial variables; first one is just an identity number, second one is 'time' and third is 'cens'. Both time and cens are needed for the Survdiff package. But from this, we know that we want to loop through the remaining variables in the data.frame i.e. Genedata[,4:43000]

What I've done so Far
I would normally use the for statement but in R i'm aware that this is potentially much slower than the apply statement.

```
cols <- as.list( names(Genedata) ) #generate a list of column numbers
Geneset <- lapply(cols , function (x) { survdiff( Surv( Genedata$time, Genedata$cens=="1" ) ~ x , data = Genedata )$chisq } )
```

However - I am getting an error

```
"Error in model.frame.default(formula = Surv(Genedata$time, Genedata$cens ==  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'x')"
```

**Sample of the data** (First 15 rows and 8 columns) - **note: the headers have overflowed**

```
Accession   time    cens    A1BG.229819_at  A1BG_AS1.232462_s_at    A1CF.220951_s_at    A1CF.241547_at  A2LD1.232422_at
1   120 0   0   0   0   0   1
2   120 0   0   0   0   0   1
3   28.96   NA  1   0   0   0   1
4   119.21  0   0   0   0   0   1
5   59.53   0   0   1   0   0   1
6   68.81   1   0   0   0   0   1
7   82.29   0   0   0   0   0   1
8   110.82  0   0   0   0   0   1
9   65.88   NA  1   0   0   0   1
10  84.13   0   0   0   0   0   1
11  16.47   NA  0   0   0   0   1
12  89.75   0   0   0   1   1   1
13  76.07   0   0   0   0   0   1
14  67.82   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

**Problems**

1. I'm not sure how to properly use 'apply' in this situation,
   because the function is more complex.

**Update1**

Changed to FUN=function(x).... now error is gone. Instead I get

```
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

yet dim(GeneMatrix) returns positive values...

**Update2**

Updated code after more tweaks

Comment: A reproducible example would help - I strongly recommend reading `?apply`, at least looking at the arguments required

Comment: I think you're problem is in `~ GeneMatrix[,i]` - what is `i`? There is no loop working here - but it's hard to check without any example data

Comment: seq(4,ncol(GeneMatrix)) should generate a sequence of numbers from 4:length of GeneMatrix for the loop. 

So when I do ~GeneMatrix[,i], the numbers will be inserted. Each of these are the variables I want to use in survdiff. These variables have 177 observations each of 1 or 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is still pretty unclear. You really, really need to give a reproducible example. What is `cens`? Is that something you're wanting to break the data up by? Try posting rows 1:15 and columns 1:8 of your data.

Comment: Posted as per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the help page for [apply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html). In this instance you are not using it correctly.

It applies a function over the margins of an array and you haven't supplied an array or an argument to state the margin (row/columns) to apply the function over anyway. Instead use a list and [lapply](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

The other problem is you write `function(x)` in apply, but try to loop with `GeneMatrix[,i]`. Instead GeneMatrix[,x] should work.

So try

```
cols <- as.list( names(Genedata) )[-c(1:4)] #generate a list of column numbers
Geneset <- lapply( cols , function (x) { survdiff( Surv( time, cens=="1" ) ~ get(x) , data = Genedata )$chisq } )
```

Hope that helps. Let us know if it doesn't. I changed the arguments of Surv from `time` to `GeneMatrix$time`, but I'm not sure if you need to do that.

Comment: I did read all the apply help articles, but still confused me as I am relatively new to R.  

I made a mistake in my original question. the Survdiff function won't actually take matrices. So i've revised it to a data.frame. The problem is a new error as per the revised question.

Comment: And what happens if you try the survdiff function on a couple of named columns? Such as `survdiff( Surv( Genedata$time, Genedata$cens=="1" ) ~ A1BG.229819_at , data = Genedata )`. It seems like you might have some missing data. Is there a way to handle this in the function? Also you don't want all names of GeneMatrix so use `cols <- as.list( names(Genedata) )[-c(1:4)] `

Comment: Do you get different results/error messages if you try `survdiff( Surv( Genedata$time, Genedata$cens=="1" ) ~ A1BG.229819_at , data = Genedata )` and then also try `survdiff( Surv( time, cens=="1" ) ~ A1BG.229819_at , data = Genedata )`?

Comment: If i plug in the actual header name, it works. Putting Genedata$time works as does just time.

Comment: @PyPerUser does the edited answer code work for you? Using `get(x)` should hopefully allow the function to evaluate properly. If it works I will try to add to the explanation of why it works. If it doesn't I will go back to the drawing board! Thanks

Comment: @PyPerUser Well I'm not entirely sure, but internally I think that for some reason `lapply` is coercing the `x` to `"x"` so it evaluates it as the character `x` which would cause the error. `get` takes a character vector as its first argument and looks to see if there is a value bound to it in the specified environment (current by default). If it doesn't find `x` it will carry on up the enclosing frames until it encounters x and returns it, or returns an error because it can't find it. That is my bad explanation of what is going on. Hope someone with more knowledge can expand/correct me

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's what I'd do. I'm assuming `GeneData` is a dataframe. I have no idea if this will be practical on your data (given its size).

```
#Make some example data
df <- data.frame(id=1:100, time=rep(c(0,1),each=50), cens=sample(0:1,100,replace=T,prob=c(0.9,0.1)), X1=sample(0:1,100,replace=T),X2=sample(0:1,100,replace=T),X3=sample(0:1,100,replace=T))

#Melt data into long form (yours will be very long)
library(reshape2)
df.m <- melt(df, id.vars=names(df)[1:3],variable.name="gene")

#Use ddply (from plyr) to operate on each gene's data (I'm guessing they're genes)
library(plyr)    
GeneSet <- ddply(df.m, .(gene), function(x){
  a <- survdiff(Surv(time, cens=='1') ~ value,x)
  a$chisq
})
#> GeneSet
#  gene        V1
#1   X1 0.5041291
#2   X2 0.1222732
#3   X3 2.3488909
```

Try it out on a few columns first. Someone may be able to get apply working for you, but I'm only really knowledgeable about `reshape` and `plyr`

Comment: This works! thanks! Still keen on seeing if there is a way to do it using apply as people have said there are gains in speed. Although running system.time on this over a dataset of 26 variables shows 0.00. Thanks for your help again :)

Comment: could you quickly explain why you've used "~ value,x" it doesn't seem like you've defined "value" but the function still works.

Comment: ~value is because that's what the melt function calls that column. You can specify it to be something else, but I didn't know what it represented. As @SimonO101 has shown you, apply is really not what you need, but lapply. I like the plyr family because theooutput is so predictable and easy to use in further applications, but for large datasets there is a pretty marked drop in performance. I'm surprised no one has chimed in with a data.table solution...